# Am I allowed to write: $(-2 + 2i)^6 = 2^6(-1 + i)^6$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I'm caught by a doubt.

Having $z = (-2 + 2i)^6$,
may I write it this way, before searching for a polar representation?

$z = (-2 + 2i)^6 = 2^6(-1 + i)^6$ ?

Comment: Yes, integer powers of complex numbers can be handled just like the case of real numbers.

Comment: Not all power rules hold in the complex numbers , but this one does.

Comment: Just a further suggestion towards the fact that you are looking for a "polar representation"; avoid just factoring out from HCF, because $2^6$ is not the correct radius for the above complex number in polar form. Instead, use $\tan{\theta} = \frac{a}{b}, z = a + bi$. Maybe, here is fun math website to start your search: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/de-moivres-formula.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity in writing $2^6$, unlike writing something like $2^\frac{1}{6}$ where there are six possible complex solutions. Because of this, the *complex* number $2^6$ has an argument of zero. Let's say that in polar form, $-1+i = re^{i\theta}$, then you can write your complex number as

$z=(-2+2i)^6=(2(-1+i))^6 = (2re^{i\theta})^6=2^6(re^{i\theta})^6=2^6(-1+i)^6$.

The punchline is that you can indeed take out the factor of two from the brackets before going to polar form under the caveat that (as geetha290krm noted) the power is an integer. If it is not, you will have to take more care.